# Cannot set minHeight and minWidth in SimpleModal jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I have read from documentation how can I set minheight and minwidth of modal dialog.

```
$("#sample").modal({
    minHeight:400,
    minWidth: 600
});
```

However, even if I rewrite the sample html from

```
<a href='#' class='basic'>Demo</a>
```

to

```
<a href onclick="$('#basic-modal-content').modal({ minHeight: 1000, minWidth: 1000 });" >Demo</a>
```

Modal dialog has still the same default width and height. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I managed to set minHeight and minWidth when I commented default width/height in plugins's css ... it's a bug ?

Comment: can u show your working page ?

Comment: Have you tried the 1.4 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar experience using version 1.3.5. However, I set the width and the height in the basic.css to be auto and that seemed to solve the problem